# why i m getting my cms page and myWeb page from same route?

Tags: vue-storefront

> consider i have a url that is
> `http://localhost:3000/default/customer-service` here
> `customer-service` is my `Cms` page and i m fetching that `Cms` page
> but if i write here my pages from route like
> `http://localhost:3000/default/myCustomPage` it will also render that
> page by i think it should render route page or `Cms` page tell me why
> its happening and what is its solution btw i m working with `vue storefront`